# C# - Have discord bot execute function upon certain phrase being said (not a prefix command)

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

So I've completed the majority of the commands I wanted to implement for my discord bot.

The < [Group("GroupName")] > functionality is pretty straightforward and easy to understand with the updated Discord.NET. However, unlike in the 0.9.6 version, I have no idea how to allow the bot to execute a function without waiting on the prefix being registered. 
enter code here

```
    public async Task HandleCommand(SocketMessage messageParam)
    {
        // Don't process the command if it was a System Message
        var message = messageParam as SocketUserMessage;
        if (message == null) return;
        // Create a number to track where the prefix ends and the command begins
        int argPos = 0;
        // Determine if the message is a command, based on if it starts with '!' or a mention prefix
        if (!(message.HasCharPrefix('$', ref argPos) || message.HasMentionPrefix(client.CurrentUser, ref argPos))) return;
        // Create a Command Context
        var context = new CommandContext(client, message);
        // Execute the command. (result does not indicate a return value, 
        // rather an object stating if the command executed successfully)
        var result = await commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, services);
        if (!result.IsSuccess)
            await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result.ErrorReason);
    }
```

Copy-pasted straight from the Foxbot guide. Now I understand that it either waits for a '$' or an @bot mention before registering a command.

What I want to do is have the bot be able to look for a certain webpage url (http://archiveofourown.org/), and without having a user request it, load the page and print out certain elements from said webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have the following line of code

```
if (!(message.HasCharPrefix('$', ref argPos) || message.HasMentionPrefix(client.CurrentUser, ref argPos))) return;
```

The `Return;` makes it that your command handling stops if the condition is not matched. Which in this case is the prefix or bot mention check.

You can expand this piece of code to first execute a piece of code before determining that it doesn't have to do anything.

```
if (!(message.HasCharPrefix('$', ref argPos) || message.HasMentionPrefix(client.CurrentUser, ref argPos)))
{
    if(check if there is a website)
    {
      // if there is a wesbite, do whatever you want to do with it
    }
    return; // still return here, as you don't want further command execution
}
```